# Scrollable html list in libgdx

Tags: list, libgdx

I want to make achievements table in my libgdx game. Is there any component in libgdx wchih i can use? For example something that allows me to turn screen into html page or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple test for you start:

**Variable Class:**

```
Stage stage;
ScrollPane scrollPane;
Table outerTable, innerTable;
```

.

```
@Override
public void show() {

    stage      = new Stage();
    outerTable = new Table();
    innerTable = new Table();
    image      = new Image(new Texture(
                           Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")));

    //innerTable.add(YourActor); for example Image, or TextButton 

    innerTable.add(image);

    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(innerTable); 

    outerTable.setPosition(0, 0);
    outerTable.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    outerTable.debug();

    outerTable.add(scrollPane).fill().expand();

    stage.addActor(outerTable);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}
```

look this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table

I hope I have understood correctly, and that this is what you want.