# LibGDX: A screen with 20 Rectangles that can be scrolled

Tags: android, libgdx

I need to create a menu with 20 vertical Rectangles in LibGdx.

The height of the rectangles is the entire height of the device.

The width of the rectangles is a set 20.0f

I have: `private Stage stage;` to which I intend to add on to my Rectangles.

The class is called LevelSelectScreen and implements Screen.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class LevelSelectScreen implements Screen {
    private Stage stage;

    private int stageNumber = 20;

    Array<Rectangle> stageRectangles;

    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    public LevelSelectScreen(){
        stage = new Stage();

        stageRectangles = new Array<Rectangle>(stageNumber);
        for(int i = 0;i<stageNumber;i++){
            stageRectangles.get(i).setWidth(20f);
            stageRectangles.get(i).setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            stageRectangles.get(i).setPosition(new Vector2(20*i,0));
        }

        Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();

        //shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);

        for(int i = 0;i<stageNumber;i++){
            Rectangle r = stageRectangles.get(i);
            shapeRenderer.rect(r.x, r.y, r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());

        }
        shapeRenderer.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Nothing appears and I don't think I'm using the Shape Renderer correctly.

How do I properly set up my scrollable rectangles?

### Edit

Also, found [this helpful link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ScrollPaneTest.java).

Comment: maybe you want to look like this helps you to believe what I think you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592083/scrollable-html-list-in-libgdx/28593139#28593139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Varible class:**

```
private Stage stage;

private int stageNumber = 20;

Array<Rectangle> stageRectangles;

ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

//new, for no magic number, but not required

private float w = 20f;
private float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

private float space = 5;
private float xPos = w + space; 
private float yPos = 0;
```

**In your code:**

```
public LevelSelectScreen(){
    stage = new Stage();   


 stageRectangles = new Array<Rectangle>(stageNumber);

    for(int i = 0; i<stageNumber; i++){

        stageRectangles.add(new Rectangle(xPos * i,
                                          yPos,
                                          w, 
                                          h));

                Gdx.app.log("Rectangle add", ""+i);
   }

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}
```

you say that does not work or that I understand, but you're not having a Nullpointer or BoundsException ? anyway grabbing a few adjustments to your code this is what I have, it's what you wanted.

[image]

**PS:** do not would be more comfortable using a scroll and a table for when you have to use the listener, pictures ect, but it's just an idea, I hope you have understood what you were saying

***in your code:***

```
for(int i = 0; i<stageNumber; i++){
            stageRectangles.get(i).setWidth(20f);
            stageRectangles.get(i).setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            stageRectangles.get(i).setPosition(new Vector2(25*i,0));
}
```

.

in this point `stageRectangles.get(i).setWidth(20f);` 
the size is 0, then the array has an initial capacity
of 20 but is empty.

not getting something like this?

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size 0 >= 0

Comment: For some reason, the error had not appeared. Thank you for this answer.